# Why does Ubuntu come with three different software update managers preinstalled?

Tags: updates, software-center

I just installed 18.04 (Bionic Beaver). I noticed that when I search my applications for the word "Software", there are three different software-update-manager type things preinstalled (maybe they're not all exactly software update managers, but they all have "update software" in their description) - "Ubuntu Software", "Software & Updates", and "Software Updater":

[image]

Isn't this a bit confusing and duplicative? What are the differences between the three applications, and is there any reason they aren't combined into just one or two applications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From left to right:

- Software & Updates is a utility for managing repositories. You can
  change update mirrors, add/remove PPAs, etc. There is no way to install anything, other then a few graphics and wifi drivers.
- Ubuntu Software is just a user friendly way for
  installing/uninstalling software.
- Software Updater is for updates, and upgrades. You can't install programs or manage repositories.

Comment: Thanks. However it looks like you can manage updates through Ubuntu Software. Therefore, it seems to me that logically Software & Updates should be folded into Software Updater (since it's basically just settings for Software Updater), which in turn should folded into Ubuntu Software.

Comment: It used to be the case that modularity was considered important. Now, everything will "fold" into systemd in a few years, just wait and see. :~)